# Find element in array --> Method post. Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

When I login in app, ws post me and my user permission, like this json

```
   {"StatusCode":0,"StatusMessage":"Authentificated Successfully",
    "Token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIs",
    "StatusDescription":{
    "Role":"admin",
    "Permissions":["homeboxpackageactivate",
    "eventscreate",
    "pollinglivememory",
    "pollinglivememorygetall",
    "usersgetall",
    "app_rolescreate",
    "app_rolesupdatebyid"
     ....]}}
```

Can you suggest me how to find my permissions from this array?

I create

```
canActivate(component: string): boolean {
        return this.permissions && this.permissions.find(x => x.permissin_desc === component) != null;
    }
```

in html code I use *ngIf like this:

```
*ngIf="ws.canActivate('usersgetall')"
```

In this, don't show nothing because i control outside my array Permissions. Can you help please?

Comment: "Permissions" !== "permissions"

Comment: If you want to use find you have to do `this.permissions && Boolean(this.permissions.find(p => p === component))`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to check if `Permissions` array contains `component` value or not and for that you can use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
canActivate(component: string): boolean {
   return this.Permissions && this.Permissions.includes(component);
}
```

Note the case of your `Permission` property.

Comment: return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.Login), body, { headers: headers    })  .map((response: Response) => { let res = response.json();        console.log(res.StatusDescription)  if (res.StatusCode === 0 && res.Token) { this.currentUser = {username: username, token: res.Token }
          localStorage.setItem(AuthService.CURRENT_USER, JSON.stringify(this.currentUser));  return true;  } else {  return false;  }   }); --> How to call form .map please?